# Ethical Hack Changing Request Headers to Access Restricted Page ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms, request-headers

I received results back for an ethical hack assessment for one of my asp.net webforms sites.  One of the items was a multi step way the hacker changed the request to display a page he shouldn’t have had access to with his user privileges.  Below are the steps he performed to execute the hack:

1) logged in using Admin level rights.
2) navigated to page ‘A’.
3) using his Burp tool, saved a copy of the page headers.
4) he then logged in using a User account which shouldn’t be able to see page ‘A’.
5) goes back to the home page to get a fresh request.
6) using his Burp tool, opens the request headers for the home page and replaces them with the contents he saved from page ‘A’.
7) he continues on with the request and is now able to see the contents of page ‘A’.

I tried to programmatically check the request.url and compare it against what pages the user has access to but the hacker said that didn’t fix it.

Is there a built in way to prevent this in ASP.NET 4.x?  Is there some web.config property I can set to stop someone from changing the request headers and performing this kind of hack?

Update: This was happening because the username and usertype was being stored in session variables after authentication.  Once the hacker gained access to the session, they replaced the session of the ‘User’ with the session of the ‘Admin’ account and it was just as if the Admin was logged in.  The fix was to not store the username and usertype in session variables.  I also created a table with the pages that each usertype was able to access and checked that each time a user comes to a page.  If the usertype does not have access to the page, they get redirected back to the homepage.  Both of these fixed the issue and eventually passed the ethical hack.

Comment: A couple of questions. 1. When you say in step 6, replaced headers, does that also include cookies? 2. In step 7, page A was accessible as the User account or as the Admin account?

Comment: For step 6, the hacker did not mention anything about cookies but he did say he made sure he had a new asp.net session id.  Page ‘A’ was accessible as User but shouldn’t be.

Comment: Can you share some details on what were the changes in the headers?

Comment: Unsure how anyone here would _guess_ for you. Nobody knows how you implemented your authentication/authorization system. Bottom line, `HTTP headers` are standard pieces of information and they can definitely be manipulated - it doesn't matter if it's `Asp.net` or some other application platform. If I were to guess, it's in how Sessions are implemented.

Comment: EdSF, looks like you may be right about the Session.  I added some more logging so I could get a closer look at what’s happening.  Turns out, when the asp.net session id of the User is replaced with the session id of the Admin, the request acts as if it is an Admin and displays the page to the user.  Did a search for this behavior and it looks to be called Session Hijacking.  Supposedly adding SSL to the site should solve the problem.  Other than adding SSL, do you have any other suggestions how to solve this?